# Can't find variable: require

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am running this simple piece of code and I got this error and my browser when I select "inspect element".

Code :

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myFunc = function() {
        $scope.location = 1;
        var csv = require('csv-parser')
        var fs = require('fs')
        console.log('test');
    }
}]);
```

Error :

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide code and errors as text, not images. No one is going to search the internet for an image of code and find this problem.

Comment: Also, a simple search finds [many, many, many questions about this same error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=can%27t+find+variable+require) perhaps you could tell us which ones you've tried?

Comment: Just edited. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Regarding what I have tried. It is as you said complicated as a lot of people have asked the question. Therefore, each case seem specific, I tried to install ReactJS for e.g., did not work.

Comment: I would say that trying to install RequireJS, and showing how you've included that in your code, would be a very critical piece of information towards debugging the problem. Please do [edit] that information into your question.

Comment: Thanks Mike. 
What command did you use to install reactJS ?

Comment: I reinstalled it via npm install reactjs. The error is still the same. Even if I add -g or --save

Comment: You really need to do some basic tutorials on how to use JavaScript in HTML. You need to reference require.js in your HTML somewhere in order for it to load. As your answer suggests, `<script src="require.js"></script>` is one place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in angular, if you want to use anything like a csv parser you need to include the corresponding library file ( or you can use bower to install it). and then add that file into your html using

`<script src="">`

i guess what you are using is the npm package csv-parser

Comment: I did not added any source. I figured out that the require will grab automatically the source in the corresponding folder.

I am indeed using npm csv-parser.
Here is the documentation : it does not say to add any source in the html file.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser

Comment: I think each case is specific as you there are many many questions like this one. Any idea of how to move forward ?

Comment: i think this can be used only in node js since in node you can use "require" command. in angular in order to parse csv you can check if there is any js file available to do so and then add script src